# Error installing Libra CMS

Tags: zend-framework2, symlink, composer-php

I'm following the installation steps listed here:

https://bitbucket.org/libracms/libra-cms

But I get the following error on step #3:

```
symlink(): Could not fetch file information(error 3)
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

I'm on Windows 7.

This is step #3

```
php composer.phar update
```

This is the output it generates:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
  - Installing libra/jquery-assets (dev-default tip)
    Cloning tip

Script LibraAssetsInstaller\Installer::postPackageInstall handling the post-pack
age-install event terminated with an exception



  [ErrorException]
  symlink(): Could not fetch file information(error 3)



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-custom-instal
lers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [
packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Comment: I'll note that though @Sam edited out the zend-framework2 tag, this CMS *is* a ZF2 cms; that said though, the error looks like a composer error. Please provide more information. The error *must* say more than that, or have some more context?

Comment: @David I agree, in fact I actually found Libra by searching for a CSM written using ZF2, so I'm adding the tag back. I amended the question adding the complete output from composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `LibraAssetsInstaller\Installer::postPackageInstall` is failing because `postPackageInstall` contains [function calls](https://bitbucket.org/vnagara/libra-assets-installer/src/f312f66a308e3543ef9e4ab9d46ad52bf54cc242/src/LibraAssetsInstaller/Installer.php?at=default#cl-32) that will likely not work on windows for a number of reasons: [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#101213) are [two](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#71880).

That said, `postPackageInstall` is failing [here specifically](https://bitbucket.org/vnagara/libra-assets-installer/src/f312f66a308e3543ef9e4ab9d46ad52bf54cc242/src/LibraAssetsInstaller/Installer.php?at=default#cl-33), likely because the paths in the call to `symlink` are not windows compatible.

To make the calls interoperable with windows, the path strings need to be revised to at least use something like the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` system constant [mentioned here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#53075), but there may be other revisions needed as well.